# Cannot click on anything while threads are running

Tags: multithreading, graphics

I am very new to "Multithreading".  I have an awt graphics program that displays 8 "snakes" that continuously grown in length.  Each snake is in its own thread.  I have the synchronization working so the snakes are drawn properly.  The problem is I cannot close the program.  Even though I specified:

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

the window will not close when I click the [X].  Alt-F4 also does not work.  Even right clicking the java icon in the task bar and selecting "close" will not close the application.

I changed the while(true) loop in the thread's run method to while (!done).  I then added KeyListener and tried to set done equal to true when any key was pressed.  Did not work.  I also tried using MouseListener and tried to set done equal to true whenever the mouse button was pressed.  Still nothing.  I finally created a more involved JFrame with a BorderLayout.  I put the Canvas in the center and I placed a button in the bottom (PAGE_END).  I added an ActionListener to the button that sets done equal to true AND calls System.exit(0).  Still nothing.  As long as my GUI threads are running, nothing else functions.  However, I can click the "End" button in jGRASP (the IDE I use) and it stops the program right away.  jGRASP was written in Java, so there must be a way to click something and stop a threaded GUI program.

Here is the complete code of the program:

```
// MultiThreadedSnakes.java

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultiThreadedSnakes
{
   public static void main(String args[])  
   {
      Snakes tester = new Snakes();
      tester.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
}

////////////////////////////////////////

class Snakes extends JFrame     
{
   private Container contentPane;
   private MyCanvas canvas;
   private JButton stopButton;

   public Snakes()
   {
      super("MultiThreadedSnakes");
        
      stopButton = new JButton("Stop Execution and Close Window");
      stopButton.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,48));
      stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
      {
         Marble.terminate(); // stop animation
         Util.delay(1000);   // wait 1 seconed
         System.exit(0);     // close window
      }});
  
      contentPane = getContentPane();
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      contentPane.add(stopButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); 
      contentPane.add(new MyCanvas(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setSize(1320,820);
      setVisible(true);       
   }       
}

////////////////////////////////////////////     

class Marble implements Runnable
{
   private Marble[] marbles;
   private int width, height;   // dimensions of the window boundaries
   private int size;        // diameter of the marble
   private int xCoord, yCoord;  // coordinates of the marble
   private int incX, incY;  // X & Y increment values for the next marble position
   private Color clr;       // marble color
   private Graphics g;
   private static boolean done = false;

   public Marble(int w, int h, int x, int y, int adjustX, int adjustY, Graphics g, Color c, Marble[] m)
   {
      marbles = m;
      width = w;
      height = h;
      size = 30;
      xCoord = x;
      yCoord = y;
      incX = adjustX;
      incY = adjustY;
      clr = c;
      this.g = g;
   }

   public static void terminate()
   {
      done = true;
   }

   public static boolean isDone()
   {
      return done;
   }   

   public void moveMarble()
   {
      Random rnd = new Random();
      xCoord += incX;
      yCoord += incY;

      if (xCoord <= 0)
         incX = (rnd.nextInt(11) + 1);
      else if (xCoord >= width - size)
         incX = -(rnd.nextInt(11) + 1);
    
      if (yCoord <= 0)
         incY = (rnd.nextInt(11) + 1);
      else if (yCoord >= height - size)
         incY = -(rnd.nextInt(11) + 1);
   }

   public void showMarble()
   {
      synchronized(marbles)
      {
         g.setColor(clr);
         g.fillOval(xCoord,yCoord,size,size);
      }   
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(!done)
      {
         showMarble();
         Util.delay(10);
         moveMarble();
      }
   }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

class MyCanvas extends Canvas
{
   private int maxX, maxY, midX, midY;
   private int numMarbles;
   private Marble[] marbles;   
   private Thread[] threads;
   
   public MyCanvas()
   {
      setSize(1320,760);
      setVisible(true);   
      maxX = 1300;
      maxY = 700;
      midX = maxX / 2;
      midY = maxY / 2;
      numMarbles = 8;
      marbles = new Marble[numMarbles];
      threads = new Thread[numMarbles+1];    
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      Util.delay(500);
      g.setColor(Color.white);
      g.fillRect(0,0,1320,760);    
      marbles[0] = new Marble(maxX,maxY, 50, 50,5,5,g,Color.red,marbles);
      marbles[1] = new Marble(maxX,maxY,100,100,5,5,g,Color.green,marbles);
      marbles[2] = new Marble(maxX,maxY,150,150,5,5,g,Color.blue,marbles);
      marbles[3] = new Marble(maxX,maxY,200,200,5,5,g,Color.orange,marbles);
      marbles[4] = new Marble(maxX,maxY,250,250,5,5,g,Color.gray,marbles);
      marbles[5] = new Marble(maxX,maxY,300,300,5,5,g,Color.pink,marbles);
      marbles[6] = new Marble(maxX,maxY,350,350,5,5,g,Color.yellow,marbles);
      marbles[7] = new Marble(maxX,maxY,400,400,5,5,g,Color.black,marbles);

      for (int t = 0; t < numMarbles; t++)
      {
         threads[t] = new Thread(marbles[t]);
         threads[t].start();
      } 
  
      while (!Marble.isDone())
      {
         Util.delay(1000);
         System.out.println(Marble.isDone());
      }
   }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Util
{
   public static int random(int min, int max)
   {
      int range = max - min + 1;
      return (int) (Math.random() * range + min);
   }

   public static void delay(int n)
   {
      long startDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long endDelay = 0;
      while (endDelay - startDelay < n)
         endDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh, when I first wrote this program, the idea was to have 8 "marbles" moving around.  When I saw the output, I started referring to them as "snakes" but I forgot to change the name of the Marble class.

Comment: I can't answer, but one thing I'd do differently is have _one_ thread that moves and shows all of the marbles in a list instead of using a thread per marble. Another thing I'd do differently is not use [AWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit). The team that created AWT realized that it was deeply flawed, and they started to work on its replacement—[Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java))—almost immediately after AWT was released. There's also [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) which is much newer, but somehow its future is less certain.

Comment: `paint` method must be as quick as possible, you must not do this in paint thread `while (!Marble.isDone()) {Util.delay(1000)}`

Comment: Yes, I hear what you are saying.  I probably should have clarified.  My goal with this program is not actually the creation of 8 animated snake-like objects.  If it were, I would not use multithreading at all.  I am a computer science teacher.  In my most advanced class (one that has AP Computer Science-A as a prerequisite) students learn the skills necessary to create video games.  This year, I want to add a unit on Multithreading.  Which means I need to teach myself before I teach them.  The text-based programs I wrote works fine, but the class I am teaching is Advanced Graphics Programming.

Comment: If I do not have a while (!done) loop in the paint method, the program stops right away before anything is displayed.  I have also tried using join.  I can join any of the threads, even the "current thread" and the output displays, but then I cannot close the window.

Comment: I clearly see such loop in your code

Comment: Yes, I know the loop is there.  If I remove it, the program does not display anything because the paint method ends right away.  I have also tried using join with one of the threads.  Whether I use the loop or join one of the threads, it has the same result.  The program executes fine, but cannot be closed.  If I use neither, the program displays no output at all.

Comment: OS have single event queue to process everything - painting, keyboard, mouse etc. If one of the messages takes long then it impacts everything. In your case long is forever. Here is short intro on how to properly repaint components https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html. Though, I think internet must have more and better articles about that.

Comment: You should calculate Marble state and then call `repaint` so OS will find proper time to paint it. `paint` method itself must not do anything related to threads nor application lifecycle.

Comment: If _you_ would not use multiple threads to write the program, then why teach kids to do it? If you want to teach them to use threads, then give them problems for which multi-threading is an appropriate solution. If you want to teach them to write video games, then give them tools that are appropriate for that task. (_Anything_ but AWT! It's literally been obsolete since 1997.)